# pthread_rwlock_rdlock gives weird errno?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, errno

I'm calling `pthread_rwlock_rdlock()` which fails for some reason.
I tried printing the `errno` and got :

> errno = 25.

The weird thing is that right after the `errno` itselt, I'm printing its meaning, and I get:

> Inappropriate ioctl for device.

According to *errno.h*:

```
#define ENOTTY      25  /* Not a typewriter */
```

So something is wrong.

My parameters for the print are:

```
 errno, strerror(errno)
```

What is my real error?

Comment: your "real error" is expecting [`pthread_rwlock_rdlock`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/pthread_rwlock_rdlock.html) to set the value of `errno` in the first place. The function  makes no warrants about setting `errno`. Rather, it directly returns its error condition. Check *that*.

Comment: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v2r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.zos.v2r1.bpxbd00%2Frp0rrl.htm

here it says that it returns -1 if unsuccessfull...and errno is set..

my pthread_rwlock_rdlock returned -1

are there different versions of this functions??

Comment: Interesting that IBM says they set errno. The POSIX spec doesn't indicate it is required, no doubt in part to the fact that errno is not thread-specific. This was the reason most of the pthread stuff *returns* error conditions. If I were to guess, (famous last words) it would be there is an error in IBM's doc, or they doc'd their impl. I've *never* used errno in pthread programs for checking success of pthread api's.

Comment: You quote the z/OS documentation and tag your question Linux: So please what platform are you on?

Answer (score 0):

The pthread services return 0 if they are OK or an error code if they are KO.  So, you should get the result of the function in a variable and display the corresponding error message:

```c
int rc = pthread_rwlock_rdlock(...);

if (rc != 0) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error %s (%d)\n", strerror(rc), rc);
}
```

According to the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) of pthreads, it is said that `errno` is not set by the services. The error code is a return value:

> **Pthreads function return values**
> Most pthreads functions return 0 on success, and an error number
> on failure.  The error numbers that can be returned have the same
> meaning as the error numbers returned in errno by conventional
> system calls and C library functions.  Note that the pthreads
> functions do not set errno.  For each of the pthreads functions
> that can return an error, POSIX.1-2001 specifies that the
> function can never fail with the error EINTR.

Concerning the message corresponding to **ENOTTY** error code, there is actually a discrepancy between the message defined in the C library's internal tables and the one exposed in the comment of the header file. For [historical reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_a_typewriter), the Linux device drivers return **ENOTTY** when they are passed an invalid operation code (instead of **ENOSYS** or **EINVAL** for examples). So, the C library has evolved to display a more meaningful error message for **ENOTTY**:

```
Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

instead of:

```
$ cat /usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h | grep ENOTTY
#define ENOTTY      25  /* Not a typewriter */
```